# How to export static images on Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, next.js, nextjs-image, next-images

when I want to export my nextjs app, it says that I cannot export my images on static websites.

> Error: Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`.
> Possible solutions:
> - Use `next start` to run a server, which includes the Image Optimization API.
> - Use any provider which supports Image Optimization (like Vercel).
> - Configure a third-party loader in `next.config.js`.
> - Use the `loader` prop for `next/image`.

How can I make it so that it does ?

Is there a way for me to simply tell it to render images statically ? I dont want to go throught other onlines images loaders..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to set up a custom image loader in Next.js

In your `next.config.js` file, add this property to the export:

```js
images: {
  loader: "custom"
}
```

---

And make a script called `loader.js` that exports this:

```js
function imageLoader({ src }) {
  return `/images/${src}`; // REPLACE WITH YOUR IMAGE DIRECTORY
}

module.exports = imageLoader;
```

---

For each `Image` component, set the `loader` prop manually:

```
const imageLoader = require("PATH TO loader.js");

<Image loader={imageLoader} />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer. Where should I put my loader.js ? It says in my < Image /> that it does not exist

Thank you very much again

Comment: you can put it wherever you want, maybe in a separate folder outside of your components -- make sure to export the function and import it from each file

Comment: Thank you very much. With some more insights and look on the code of the page, I've found that in the return section we only need the ${src} .
Thank you very very much. I hope you are well where you are. You are the reason why I am going to sleep right now thank you sooo much.

Comment: This approach won't work, you need to provide a URL to a third-party cloud provider (not a local path) where the image is hosted when using a custom loader. The optimization needs to happen somewhere, in this case the third-party service.

Comment: @juliomalves OP wanted to host their images locally so I gave the solution -- may not give you the most optimized images but it will still work

Comment: I get you, but it will render the image as is, which kinda defeats the purpose of using the `next/image` component since its main benefit is the optimizations it brings. Might as well just use an `<img>` tag instead when using `next export`.

Comment: @juliomalves yeah, I guess using an `img` tag would work, but it doesn't behave the exact same way as the `Image` component so it could create inconsistencies -- i just prefer this approach since it's easy to substitute in a different image loader whenever necessary -- doesn't really have much of a drawback either

Answer (score 26):

I created a npm module so that we can use the Next.js <Image/> component with optimized images while using the static export functionality.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-image-export-optimizer

The library wraps the <Image /> component of Next.js and automatically creates optimized images using sharp.js at export time.

It uses a custom loader to create a srcset for the <img /> that the <Image /> component of Next.js creates. Then at build/export time, the images inside the public/images folder (as an example) are optimized with sharp.js and copied into the build folder.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!  I have a completely static site but need a few images, and the idea of adding node to my deployed environment and losing export functionality was offensive to my senses.  Appreciate the great README and good API design.

Comment: AMAZING WORK! It is sad that this functionality is not built in Next.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to add onto skara9's answer because it didn't quite work for me. I found a [thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19065) on github discussing it and the answer there worked for me. It just wraps around the NextJS image component and works pretty flawlessly for me.

```
// components/Image.js
import NextImage from "next/image";

// opt-out of image optimization, no-op
const customLoader = ({ src }) => {
  return src
}

export default function Image(props) {
  return (
    <NextImage
      {...props}
      loader={customLoader}
    />
  );
}
```

Make sure you change your imports and update your `next.config.js`

```
import Image from '../components/Image.js'
```

Answer (score 4):

The most simple solution now is to just opt-out of next Image optimization. This was no issue for my project. You can do this by adding this to your `next.config.js`:

```json
output: 'export',
images: {
    unoptimized: true,
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a custom loader that does not require a server runtime, which I won't recommend because:

1. It's probably easier to just use a supported cloud Image loader like `cloudinary`.
2. You could just as easy use Next's built-in image optimiser which you can launch with `next start`.

However, if you really want to use a custom preprocessor and loader, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-image-export-optimizer as mentioned in an earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want export optimized images with next.js since 2023, You can read more about it here!

https://next-export-optimize-images.vercel.app/docs/comparison#next-image-export-optimizer

install it

```
yarn add -D next-export-optimize-images
```

and use as nextjs plugin

```
const withExportImages = require(  "next-export-optimize-images");
module.exports = withExportImages({...baseConfig, output: "export"})
```

then change the build script

```
{
-  "build": "next build",
+  "build": "next build && next-export-optimize-images",
}
```

is all you need to do.